# D3.js reflexive edges in directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to make directed reflexive edges in D3 library ?
I found out pretty nice example of [directed graph using D3](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) However I would like to have directed reflexive edges there.
 In example they use border around node to mark it as reflexive but I need to add label to edges as well so this is not sufficient for me.
Thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mattkohl/08fe7f53f592ab699ea15af46be04c48

Comment: thanks, I found it but those edges are NOT directed + it not nice at all. I don't need one edge to go all over 300 pixels to return to starting point... I would like to extend existing example from D3 documentation